# MP3 stream (ytdl-core) to PCM with fluent-ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, electron, lame, ytdl

So basically im trying to convert a MP3 stream, coming in from an NodeJS readable, to the PCM format so i can play it back via the [Speaker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/speaker) Package.

I tried many things including: node-lame, lame, lamejs -> so i figured why not use the ffmpeg libary directly.

My Attempt (doesn't work):

```js
const args = " u r l "
[...]
const dl = ytdl(args, {
    filter: "audioonly",
});
const speaker = new Speaker();
ffmpeg(dl).audioCodec("libmp3lame").format("s16le").pipe(speaker);
```

It is however playing something, but it's more like pink or white noise.

Thanks in advance!

PS: i installed FFmpeg correctly 
PSS: i use this in the main process from electron but i don't see why this would make a difference

Comment: You appear to be using `libmp3lame` not a PCM encoder.

Comment: using the pcm_s16le codec fixed it thanks :)